# Change terminal tab name with ncurses in python

Tags: python, unix, terminal, ncurses

I use to change terminal tab names in python using:

```
sys.stdout.write('\x1b]2;' + name + '\x07')
```

Can this can be achieved while using ncurses? If not, is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

That's outside the scope of ncurses.

You can **write** the text as shown, but...

By default (using `initscr`) ncurses writes to the *standard output*.  You can change that to a different stream using `newterm`, but in either case, ncurses buffers its output to the screen separately from the `<stdio.h>` (standard I/O) streams.  If you happen to use the same output as ncurses, you should do a `refresh` in ncurses first, and flush the output from your `write` before resuming ncurses.

For your example, there's no complicating factors (such as printing newlines), but those could be addressed with the calls that save/restore program/shell mode.

Comment: I can't find curses newterm in the Python implementation. Are you sure it exists?

Comment: You asked about *ncurses*.  The Python *curses* binding does not provide a binding for `newterm`, so that by-the-way comment is not needed for you.